# How to update a column base on another column's value from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have a `table A`, with 2 main columns: `Name` and `Settings`.
The `Settings` column will have 3 values: 1, 2 or 3.

For ex:

```
Name     Settings
Andre        1
Andre        1
Betty        3
Charles      1
Charles      1
```

Note that 1 `Name` can only have 1 `Settings`: 1, 2 or 3

I have another `table B`, with 2 main columns: `Name` and `Type`.
The `Type` column consists of many values: `'TypeA'`, `'TypeB'`, `'TypeC'`......

For ex:

```
Name       Type
Andre      TypeA
Andre      TypeA
Andre      TypeC
Betty      TypeB
Betty      TypeB
Charles    TypeB
Charles    TypeA
Charles    TypeA
```

Note that 1 `Name` can have multiple same or not same `Type`. And we just considering about `TypeA` and `TypeB`.

Now I want to update the `Settings` column from `table A` using the `'Type'` column from `table B`, if:

- The `Type` column from `table B` is having the value of `'TypeA'`, then set all the records, which is having the same `Name` of both table, to 1 on the `Settings` column from `table A`.
- The `Type` column from `table B` is having the value of `'TypeB'`, then set all the records, which is having the same `Name` of both table, to 2 on the `Settings` column from `table A`.
- The `Type` column from `table B` is having both of the value of `'TypeA'` and `'TypeB'`, then set all the records, which is having the same `Name` of both table, to 3 on the `Settings` column from `table A`.

The result from `table A` will become like this:

```
Name     Settings
Andre        1
Andre        1
Andre        1
Betty        2
Charles      3
Charles      3
```

How can I do it?
What I've tried so far:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.Settings = CASE b.Type 
                       WHEN 'TypeA' THEN 1
                       WHEN 'TypeB' THEN 2
                    END
FROM   tablsA a
JOIN   tableB b 
ON a.name = b.name
WHERE  type IN ('TypeA', 'TypeB')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different ways to solve this. I would add a few columns to make life easier. After that, the update becomes trivial:

```
USE TEMPDB

CREATE TABLE A (Names VARCHAR (20), Sorts VARCHAR (20), A INT, B INT, AB INT)

INSERT INTO A VALUES 
('Andre'   ,   'TypeA' ,0 ,0, 0),
('Andre'   ,   'TypeA' ,0 ,0, 0),
('Andre'   ,   'TypeC' ,0 ,0, 0),
('Betty'   ,   'TypeB' ,0 ,0, 0),
('Betty'   ,   'TypeB' ,0 ,0, 0),
('Charles' ,   'TypeB' ,0 ,0, 0),
('Charles' ,   'TypeA' ,0 ,0, 0),
('Charles' ,   'TypeA' ,0 ,0, 0) 

UPDATE A
SET A = 1 
WHERE Sorts = 'TypeA'
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM A AS A2
                WHERE A.Names = A2.Names
                  AND A2.Sorts = 'TypeB' )

UPDATE A
SET B = 1 
WHERE Sorts = 'TypeB'
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM A AS A2
                WHERE A.Names = A2.Names
                  AND A2.Sorts = 'TypeA' )

UPDATE A
SET AB = 1 
WHERE Sorts = 'TypeA'
  AND  EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM A AS A2
             WHERE A.Names = A2.Names
               AND A2.Sorts = 'TypeB' )

SELECT * FROM A
```

-- EDIT: Another option is to use a CTE, since the OP can not alter or create tables. Same thing applies, after the extra's are added, you can use the CTE for the update.

```
CREATE TABLE D (Names VARCHAR (20), Sorts VARCHAR (20))
INSERT INTO D VALUES 
    ('Andre'   ,   'TypeA'),
    ('Andre'   ,   'TypeA'),
    ('Andre'   ,   'TypeC'),
    ('Betty'   ,   'TypeB'),
    ('Betty'   ,   'TypeB'),
    ('Charles' ,   'TypeB'),
    ('Charles' ,   'TypeA'),
    ('Charles' ,   'TypeA'); 

WITH CTE AS 

(
    SELECT *,
         CASE WHEN Sorts = 'TypeA' AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM D AS D2
                                                WHERE D.Names = D2.Names
                                                  AND D2.Sorts = 'TypeB' ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS A,
          CASE WHEN Sorts = 'TypeB' AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM D AS D2
                                                 WHERE D.Names = D2.Names
                                                   AND D2.Sorts = 'TypeA' ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS B,
          CASE WHEN Sorts = 'TypeB' AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM D AS D2
                                             WHERE D.Names = D2.Names
                                               AND D2.Sorts = 'TypeA' ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS AB
    FROM D
)

SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Comment: Hi, I cannot edit the `table A` structure. Can you make it without changing the structure?

Comment: @VũTrần I added an extra option, using a common table expression.

Comment: @VũTrần Did it work? If so, please accept this answer.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your contribution. It's done :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach! I have updated `TableA` thrice for three different type.

See the following code:

```
UPDATE TableA SET TableA.Settings = 1
WHERE Exists(
  SELECT 1 FROM TableB B
  WHERE TableA.Name = B.Name
  AND B.Type = 'TypeA'
)

UPDATE TableA SET TableA.Settings = 2
WHERE Exists(
  SELECT 1 FROM TableB B
  WHERE TableA.Name = B.Name
  AND B.Type = 'TypeB'
)

UPDATE TableA SET TableA.Settings = 3
WHERE Exists(
  SELECT 1 FROM TableB B1
  INNER JOIN TableB B2
  ON(B1.Name = B2.Name AND B1.Type != B2.Type)
  WHERE TableA.Name = B1.Name
  AND ((B1.Type = 'TypeA' AND B2.Type = 'TypeB')
    OR (B1.Type = 'TypeB' AND B2.Type = 'TypeA'))
)
```

[Here is the working demo!](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e66f2312cae2e29e4c393d2367fb67e0)

Hope, this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT NAME
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT TYPE) CNO
    FROM TABLEB
    WHERE TYPE <> 'TYPEC'
    GROUP BY NAME
    )
UPDATE A
SET Settings = CASE 
        WHEN T.Type = 'TypeA'
            AND C.CNO = 1
            THEN 1
        WHEN T.Type = 'TypeB'
            AND C.CNO = 1
            THEN 2
        WHEN C.CNO = 2
            THEN 3
        END
FROM TABLEA AS A
INNER JOIN CTE AS C ON A.NAME = C.NAME
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT NAME
        ,TYPE
    FROM TABLEB
    WHERE TYPE <> 'TYPEC'
    ) T ON A.NAME = C.NAME
```

Comment: Hi, actually, for the `Type` column there will be more values other than `Type A`, `'Type B'` or `'Type C'`, so maybe in the CTE it won't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Try This

> select        * into      #table1 from ( SELECT 'Andre' AS Name                               ,1 AS
>   Setting UNION ALL SELECT 'Andre'                  ,1 UNION ALL SELECT
>   'Betty'                   ,3 UNION ALL SELECT 'Charles'                   ,1 UNION ALL SELECT
>   'Charles'                 ,1 )XX
>
> select    * into      #table2 from ( SELECT   'Andre' AS Name     ,'TypeA' AS
>   Type UNION SELECT 'Andre'  ,'TypeA' UNION SELECT 'Andre'   ,'TypeC'
>   UNION SELECT 'Betty'   ,'TypeB' UNION SELECT 'Betty'   ,'TypeB' UNION
>   SELECT 'Charles'   ,'TypeB' UNION SELECT 'Charles'     ,'TypeA' UNION
>   SELECT 'Charles'   ,'TypeA' )YY
>
> UPDATE XX SET XX.Setting =    CASE 
>                         WHEN EXISTS(
>                                         SELECT
>                                             1
>                                         FROM
>                                             #table2 YY
>                                         WHERE 
>                                             YY.Name = XX.Name
>                                             AND YY.Type = 'TypeA'
>
> ```
>                                   EXCEPT 
>
>                                   SELECT  
>                                       1
>                                   FROM
>                                       #table2 YY
>                                   WHERE 
>                                       YY.Name = XX.Name
>                                       AND YY.Type = 'TypeB'
>                                   ) THEN 1
>                   WHEN EXISTS(            
>                                   SELECT  
>                                       1
>                                   FROM
>                                       #table2 YY
>                                   WHERE 
>                                       YY.Name = XX.Name
>                                       AND YY.Type = 'TypeB'
>
>                                   EXCEPT 
>
>                                   SELECT  
>                                       1
>                                   FROM
>                                       #table2 YY
>                                   WHERE 
>                                       YY.Name = XX.Name
>                                       AND YY.Type = 'TypeA'
>                                   ) THEN 2
>                   WHEN EXISTS(            
>                                   SELECT  
>                                       1
>                                   FROM
>                                       #table2 YY
>                                   WHERE 
>                                       YY.Name = XX.Name
>                                       AND YY.Type = 'TypeA'
>
>                                   INTERSECT 
>
>                                   SELECT  
>                                       1
>                                   FROM
>                                       #table2 YY
>                                   WHERE 
>                                       YY.Name = XX.Name
>                                       AND YY.Type = 'TypeB'
>                                   ) THEN 3
>               END                                                       FROM  #table1 XX
> ```